# Android Studio 1.2 Build error

Tags: java, android

I am apprentice to android but i have programming skills. I am following android app development tutorial unfortunately received below error while i'm developing a app. please help me to resolve this.

[image: error]

What i was tried so far :

1. In project structure window i have changes 'compile SDK version to
            API 22: android 5.1 version.
2. In flavors tab 'min sdk version to API 22.

but still i can see those errors in my coding. underlines in red color.

[image]

Comment: clean your project, in many case it solve this type of problem

Comment: Have cleaned the project , but nothing change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppCompat library version 23 requires `compileSdkVersion 23`.

Also, `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated, use `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer more specifically ? I'm new to this field

Comment: _In project structure window i have changes 'compile SDK version to
API 22: android 5.1 version._  --> change 22 to 23.

Answer (score 0):

1. Provide R.java file path in you import section

   ```
    import com.package.name.R;
   ```
2. File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart

And also check targetSDK version in gradle.

Answer (score 0):

To build your app, go to your app folder directory, in there there is a folder called .gradle, this folder is usually hidden so you have to find and delete it, then build your app again allow android studio to download the new .gradle contents for the app and hopefully you should not find the error again. To do this, you  have to be connected to the internet.

Comment: Flowed your guideline but nothing was changed

Comment: Okay, try this, go to the sdk manager and install the SDK for the versions you are using as your compiled and min if you don' have it. make sure the sdk is installed.

Answer (score -1):

1- Update Android Studio To 1.5.1, Rebuild Your Projectand Check Import (R) To Solve This Problem .

2- ActionBarActivity Class Deprecated.